# Event listening on a VPS server with limited ressources

Tags: dapps, events, nodes, server-side

I need to listen to events on the Ethereum blockchain on a small vps server with limited ressources (1 vcore, 10go SSD, 2go of RAM). Is it possible to do so without running a full Ethereum node ? What are the different options and their drawbacks ?

Comment: Only throught an external client, like infura.io.

Comment: Based on the link below, it appears that they are no longer supporting the function registerEvents.watch() which allows event listening: the result of this function is not deterministic because they are using a load balancer. They are still working on a solution => https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/13

Comment: I've used it together with [web3-engine-provider](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine) and their filter subprovider. But a light client should be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Logs section of the Ethereum docs :https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#logs

> Since some part of the log data is stored in bloom filters, it is
>   possible to search for this data in an efficient and cryptographically
>   secure way, so network peers that do not download the whole blockchain
>   (“light clients”) can still find these logs.

You can learn more about light clients here:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol

> - Light clients want to "watch" for events that are logged. The protocol here is the following:
>
>   - A light client gets all block headers, checks for block headers that contain bloom filters that match one of a desired list of
>       addresses or topics that the light client is interested in
>   - Upon finding a potentially matching block header, the light client downloads all transaction receipts, checks them for
>       transactions whose bloom filters match
>   - Upon finding a potentially matching transaction, the light client checks its actual log RLP, and sees if it actually matches

Both geth and parity have a light mode :

`parity --light --no-serve-light` (https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Light-Client)

`geth --syncmode "light"` (https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6lzw8y/how_to_run_ethereum_wallet_in_light_mode/)